Whatsapp send message link without new tab or new window
I want my users can trigger whatsapp messages from my web based application.
For example
<a href="https://wa.me/+905555555?text=your%20car%20is%20ready" target="_blank">Send Car Ready Message</a>

this opens https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone... link in new tab and whatsapp application appears. Then user clicks send icon.
When user wants to return browser, https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone... page is active tab. User has to close this active tab for returning my app. I want to close api.whastsapp tab automatically.
I tried the function below:


<a href="#" onclick="openWhatsApp()">Send Message</a>

<script>
function openWhatsApp() {
    const whatsappURL = "https://wa.me/+100000000?text=yourcarisready";
    const newWindow = window.open(whatsappURL, "_blank", "width=800,height=600,scrollbars=no");
    
    // close window after 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (newWindow) {
            newWindow.close();
        }
    }, 3000); 
}
</script>



but it did not work.
How can I bypass api.whatsapp page for triggering whatsapp messages?
